# Quality of R plots in LaTeX

Tags: plot, r

In `R`, I use `par` to prepare four boxplots (using `boxplot`) as a single image, which I save with the `png()` command. This image is included in a LaTeX document with `\includegraphics`. I have experimented with exporting different image sizes, and changing the scaling in LaTeX, but the image quality is still poor. I don't really have time to learn `Sweave` or `knitr` right now. What settings should I use to optimize the image quality?

Comment: Your question aims at how to change the output resolution of `R`'s `png()` command, so you are asking in the wrong place. Btw, can `R` output vector graphics like eps or pdf? Then you should use those.

Comment: My question was actually related to visualizing that output in LaTeX and my concern that doing so was reducing the quality of the image.

Comment: Consider that LaTeX will input images _as is_. This indicates that whatever images are shown with poor quality in the final PDF are due to regular poor image quality.

Comment: My understanding was that using the scale function of `\includegraphics` may result in lower quality images? Any scaling should be done outside of LaTeX. Hence my question about how to optimize the quality of an R image in LaTeX. I would have preferred that the question be moved to another site, rather than down-voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saving the image from R as a PDF rather than a PNG file solved this:

In R:

```
pdf('theFile.pdf')
# par...
# plot...
dev.off()
```

In LaTeX:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{theFile.pdf}
```

I did not specify image dimensions in R. The image quality in the final PDF was excellent, even though I scaled it to 80%.